# Why counting is(':checked') or prop('checked') radio buttons by .length returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check is any radiobuton located in one of  element is checked, but when I use my code:

```
var activeQst= jQuery('.mainTab:eq(0) tbody').children('tr:visible');
var whichQst = +activeQst.index();
var radioActive = jQuery('.mainTab:eq(0) tr:eq('+whichQst+') .RadioButton');
var checker = radioActive.is(':checked').length;
```

or

```
var checker = radioActive.prop('checked').length;
```

`alert(checker);` - returning `undefined`, even when checkbox is physically checked.
`alert(radioActive.length)` - return proper length of elements.
I couldn't find what is wrong.

Comment: can we see HTML structure..?

Comment: `is(':checked')` and `prop('checked')` will give a boolean result. Why do you want to have the length of a boolean?

Comment: `is()` returns a boolean, and you cannot apply `length` to booleans. It looks like you should test the return value of `is()` directly.

Comment: Because `is()` returns a boolean result and `prop()` returns the value of the property. Try `has()` or `filter()` instead to limit the

Comment: `is()` does not filter elements based on selector. It just *answers* if it matches the selector.

Comment: Of course, a total brain eclipse... filter() working properly, THX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
var checker = radioActive.is(':checked').length;
```

with

```
var checker = radioActive.filter(':checked').length;
```

As many said in the comments, `is()` would return a `boolean` which does not have a `length` property.